# Connect Mac with iPhone using bonjour

Tags: objective-c, ios, macos, bluetooth, bonjour

I am trying to make a connection using bonjour and bluetooth between my mac and my iPhone.

I´ve been reading a bit and from these sites I have learned that I cannot use NSNetService as I did on my first attempt.

[Bonjour over bluetooth WITHOUT Gamekit ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844189/bonjour-over-bluetooth-without-gamekit)

[Bonjour over Bluetooth on iOS 5.0](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1753/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011315)

So I have modded the DNSSDObjects sample code to use the kDNSServiceInterfaceIndexP2P flag instead.
 [DNSSDObjects](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/DNSSDObjects/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011371)

But I still cant connect my iPhone with my mac. If I change the flag back to kDNSServiceInterfaceIndexAny I can make a connection over Wifi (lan). But no luck using kDNSServiceInterfaceIndexP2P or kDNSServiceFlagsIncludeP2P using bluetooth.

Is there something missing, is it even possible to connect OSX and iOS using bonjour and bluetooth?

Comment: See my answer here for updating DNSSDObjects: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12982389/bonjour-not-advertising-over-bt/12982803#12982803

Comment: @rmaddy I've tried replacing the the flags in DNSServiceBrowse, DNSServiceRegister and DNSServiceResolve but I still cant make a connection between my mac and iPhone. I have not tried using two iOS devices. Thats why I wonder if its even possible to connect OSX and iOS. Have you been able to connect an OSX and iOS device?

Comment: No, I've only connected two iOS devices. My app is iOS-only. I just tried running the DNSSDObjects on my Mac. I tried both with -r and -b and in neither case could I get a bluetooth connection between my Mac and iOS app. It worked just fine when I enabled WiFi on iOS device. At the same time, another iOS device had no trouble connecting to the first via bluetooth. I don't know why iOS to OS X isn't working via bluetooth.

Comment: @rmaddy ok, thanks for your input. I will see if I find anything tomorrow, otherwise wifi will have to do. thanks again.

Comment: @Merdon: How did it turn out?

Comment: @M3rd0n: Are you able to connect to OSX and iOS device over bluetooth?

Comment: @Ram: No sry, I was never able to connect OSX to an iOS device using bluetooth.