# How to broadcast bluetooth service in ios using corebluetooth?

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth

If I want to have my iOS device act as a "server" and broadcast its bluetooth services to other iOS devices, how would I use the core-bluetooth framework (or any other iOS framework) to implement this?  So far, all I've seen from the corebluetooth framework is how to write the client-side of things. (Scanning, connecting to existing bluetooth services)

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the OSX sample project called DNSSDObjects. The core classes (three of them) work just fine under iOS. The code requires a few small changes to work with Bluetooth (as-is they only work with WiFi). See [my answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12982389/bonjour-not-advertising-over-bt) for the required code changes.

Basically you use whatever code you need to setup your server and begin accepting socket connections. You then use the `DNSSDRegistration` class to advertise your server via Bonjour.

The other two classes, `DNSSDBrowser` and `DNSSDService` can be used by iOS client code to find the server, or any app or program that can find Bonjour services will also be able to find your server.

Answer (score 0):

There are two great WWDC video that show how to act as either the client or the server using an appropriate iOS device.  They can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/), you're looking for sessions 703 and 705.

Downloads of the source that they use can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2012/wwdc_2012_sample_code/wwdc_2012_session_code.dmg).  You'll need a developer account (free works) to login and view/download.